# Comma-separated file with multiple commas within cell

Tags: r

For a research project, we got a large SAP database dump as CSV file. The delimiter is a comma (",").
The problem is that there are some columns where some text is stored. This messes up my data import. There is only one column with these multiple commas.

I already tried reading in the whole file as a string and then splitting the rows by using str_split(). I think a more suited way is using some regex expressions.

The "usual" data looks like this:

```
010,0040,0000399500,2018,KX,01/17/2015 00:00:00,01/17/2015 00:00:00,,ZAR,,2,,40,S,S,13860.00,VOUCHERS 126,,1000,0004301410,,0000669010,,,,0.000,,,0,0.00,ZAR,VOUCHERS,20180117,,
```

The "corrupt" data records look like this.  **CELL, PARKING, AIRFARE** are the content of one cell but will be split into three...

```
010,0040,0000399500,2018,KX,01/17/2015 00:00:00,01/23/2015 00:00:00,,ZAR,,2,,40,S,S,482.46,CELL,PARKING,AIRFARE,,1000,0004300010,,0000682110,,,,0.000,,,0,0.00,ZAR,CELL PARKING,20180123,,
```

My quite limited reproductive code snippet here.

```
mydata = read.delim("SAP_input_file.csv", sep = ",")
```

Comment: Is there a pattern to what cells are "corrupt"? Is it always the same cell that has text containing commas? Also, just to confirm, there's no way that you can repeat the database dump so that it uses a different separator or to add a quoting character around each cell?

Comment: @divibisan Unfortunately not possible to get a new dump... Yes, it is always the same column with multiple potential commas.

Comment: What about the cell after the multiple-value column? Does it have a different data type or any distinguishing characteristics? It's not hard to read it in and merge those values into one column, the tricky part is determining which values in each line are improperly split (and should be merged back into the multiple-value column) and which values are the following, correctly split columns

Comment: Could you give us a few more rows of examples with a few less columns? ~ 10 rows with a mix of corrupted cell examples and, say 2 columns before the corrupt column and 2 after would make things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two alternatives.

**1) gsubfn** Using the `input` in the Note at the end, this assumes that there are 35 fields in each row with the 17th being the one that is possibly an offending one.  There may be any number of commas including zero in the 17th field. Now create a pattern that matches such a row using capture groups, i.e. parentheses, to surround the fields. Use `read.pattern` from gsubfn with that pattern to read it in.

```
library(gsubfn)
pat <- paste0("^", strrep("([^,]*),", 16), "(.*)", strrep(",([^,]*)", 18), "$")
read.pattern(text = input, pat = pat)
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2     V3   V4 V5                  V6                  V7 V8  V9 V10 V11
1 10 40 399500 2018 KX 01/17/2015 00:00:00 01/17/2015 00:00:00 NA ZAR  NA   2
2 10 40 399500 2018 KX 01/17/2015 00:00:00 01/23/2015 00:00:00 NA ZAR  NA   2
  V12 V13 V14 V15      V16                  V17 V18  V19     V20 V21    V22 V23
1  NA  40   S   S 13860.00         VOUCHERS 126  NA 1000 4301410  NA 669010  NA
2  NA  40   S   S   482.46 CELL,PARKING,AIRFARE  NA 1000 4300010  NA 682110  NA
  V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31          V32      V33 V34 V35
1  NA  NA   0  NA  NA   0   0 ZAR     VOUCHERS 20180117  NA  NA
2  NA  NA   0  NA  NA   0   0 ZAR CELL PARKING 20180123  NA  NA
```

**2) Base R** This solution uses only base R.  We replace each of the first 16 commas with semicolons and then replace each of the last 18 commas with semicolons. Then read it in.

```
ss <- input
for(i in 1:16) ss <- sub(",", ";", ss)
for(i in 1:18) ss <- sub("(.*),", "\\1;", ss)
read.table(text = ss, sep = ";")
```

### Note

```
s1 <- "010,0040,0000399500,2018,KX,01/17/2015 00:00:00,01/17/2015 00:00:00,,ZAR,,2,,40,S,S,13860.00,VOUCHERS 126,,1000,0004301410,,0000669010,,,,0.000,,,0,0.00,ZAR,VOUCHERS,20180117,,"
s2 <- "010,0040,0000399500,2018,KX,01/17/2015 00:00:00,01/23/2015 00:00:00,,ZAR,,2,,40,S,S,482.46,CELL,PARKING,AIRFARE,,1000,0004300010,,0000682110,,,,0.000,,,0,0.00,ZAR,CELL PARKING,20180123,,"
input <- c(s1, s2)
```

### Update

Replaced original solution with the much shorter solution in (1).  Simplified original solution giving (2).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some regex can help. However, my code is not generalized, it workds for your specific example with three whole words that are separated by commas. But maybe you can expend the logic so it fits your data :)

```
x <- "010,0040,0000399500,2018,KX,01/17/2015 00:00:00,01/23/2015 00:00:00,,ZAR,,2,,40,S,S,482.46,CELL,PARKING,AIRFARE,,1000,0004300010,,0000682110,,,,0.000,,,0,0.00,ZAR,CELL PARKING,20180123,,"

library(stringr)

# regex to find three words separated by commas
pattern <- "[a-zA-Z]+,[a-zA-Z]+,[a-zA-Z]+"

# extract the pattern and replace commas with space
correct_substring <- str_extract_all(x, pattern) %>% 
  str_replace_all(",", " ")

# Insert the manipulated string into the original string
new_string <- str_replace_all(x, "[a-zA-Z]+,[a-zA-Z]+,[a-zA-Z]+", correct_string)

# Now we can split the string by commas
str_split(new_string, pattern = ",")
```

**Result**

```
    [[1]]
 [1] "010"                  "0040"                 "0000399500"           "2018"                 "KX"                  
 [6] "01/17/2015 00:00:00"  "01/23/2015 00:00:00"  ""                     "ZAR"                  ""                    
[11] "2"                    ""                     "40"                   "S"                    "S"                   
[16] "482.46"               "CELL PARKING AIRFARE" ""                     "1000"                 "0004300010"          
[21] ""                     "0000682110"           ""                     ""                     ""                    
[26] "0.000"                ""                     ""                     "0"                    "0.00"                
[31] "ZAR"                  "CELL PARKING"         "20180123"             ""                     ""
```