# Python Cleaning CSV

Tags: python

I have a csv file on a virtual machine. The csv file is essentially the data from this site:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/311-Service-Requests-from-2010-to-Present/erm2-nwe9/data

The problem arises as there are commas in certain fields, so Python thinks it's a new column. For example, X-coordinate and Y-coordinate fields are two columns (of many) that have commas within their rows.

I would like to clean this file so Python does not think that the comma within the number is a new column.

Is there a way to do this without using Pandas?

[Here is a screenshot of the CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm792.png)

Comment: The fields you are pointing out are correctly quoted. Python should be able to read them just fine with the `csv` module. I'm guessing something is wrong in your code, but you are not showing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there's different ways to achieve that.

Considering your goal is to use the data without that problem with the commas, you don't really care if it comes as CSV or any other format. So, the first thing that comes to my mind is that you can download the data as JSON or XML instead, which are two of the available methods, and go from there

[image]

If that's not an option for you and you really want the CSV, I'd create a Python script that would substitute the columns that represent a new column with semicolons, spaces or an escape character like \ or double-quotes (similar to what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57363679/5675325) with using R). To do that you know how many commas to expect before and after the columns where the problem happens.

Comment: No, the correct escaping mechanism in CSV is to put double quotes around the field; but the data already does that.

Comment: @tripleee added that info too